# Understanding how to compile C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I'm new to coding and Visual Studio. I know and understand how to create, save and compile a new C++  project in Visual Studio. I understand that a new VS project creates a solution file in the directory which then I can use to open the project, etc.

What I don't understand is how to compile a C++ project which doesn't have a VS solution file. I mean, do I have to manually create a project and import files and then build it?

Please take [this GitHub project](https://github.com/zekyll/OMPEval) as an example. Under information, it clearly states the following:

> ```
>                               Building
> ```
>
> To build a static library (./lib/ompeval.a) on Unix systems, use make.
> To enable -msse4.1 switch, use make SSE4=1. Run tests with ./test. For
> Windows there's currently no build files, so you will have to compile
> everything manually. The code has been tested with MSVC2013, TDM-GCC
> 5.1.0 and MinGW64 6.1, Clang 3.8.1 on Cygwin, and g++ 4.8 on Debian.

Now, what I don't understand is how do I build this project in my VS software so that I can successfully run it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That ReadMe seems to be pretty clear on this part: *"For Windows there's currently no build files, so you will have to compile everything manually."* There are multiple ways of doing this, creating new VS project is one of them.

Comment: There is a Makefile that can wok on windows if you use mingw instead of Visual Studio. The .a files are static libraries that gcc produces. In Visual Studio it may just work if you create a Windows console project and just add the files.

Answer (score 1):

As you said it, create a new project in Visual Studio and just import the source and header files. Looking at the makefile, there doesn't seem to be any pre or post build events so you can import the files and compile them right away (as long as the code is platform compatible ofc).

You may have to create multiple projects. One for the static library and one for the test files, since Visual Studio projects usually have one output type only. Mostly one of the presets: dynamic library (dll), static library (lib) or executable (exe).

Comment: Visual studio projects can have any kind of output, they just have built-in settings for dll, lib and exe.

Comment: @VTT true, but since OP is new to VS it's negeletiable imo, Anyway, fixed.